# Secure php script execution

Tags: php, mysql, database, crash, cron

I'm executing thousand of 'insert' in my mysql Database with a php file.
If the php crash before finishing, to be sure that my update failed, I don't want to have 5000 'insert' on 10 000 done but 0.

Can you tell me how that's possible?

Comment: Also note that PHP generally doesn't just "crash", and if it does you have other things to worry about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using a Transaction. The implementation varies depending on the database. A transaction will ensure that the entire task is completed, or none of it is, as you've described.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your operations into [Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html).

Answer (score 2):

Perform all inserts in a single [transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5bphp%5d+mysql+transaction).